# Menu Items being stacked Horizontally instead of Vertically when binding Items with v-for in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, navbar, vue-router

I am using Bootstrap 4 with vue.js Router. I have created the following Bootstrap Navbar:

```
<b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light" variant="white">
<b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
<b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
  <b-navbar-nav class="ml-auto">

    <b-nav-item-dropdown text="Dropdown" right>
      <b-dropdown-item href="#">
        <router-link class="links" v-for="routes in links"
        v-bind:key="routes.id"
        :to="`${routes.page}`">{{routes.text}}</router-link>
      </b-dropdown-item>
    </b-nav-item-dropdown>

  </b-navbar-nav>
</b-collapse>
```

I have also defined routes as follows:

```
      links: [
    {
      id: 1,
      text: 'Item1',
      page: '/Item1'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      text: 'Item2',
      page: '/Item2'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      text: 'Item3',
      page: '/Item3'
    }
  ]
```

Everything is working properly, however the Items are all displayed horizontally on a single line, instead of being stack vertically in my dropdown. How can I change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set things in flex `column` direction
There are two things you can do use css or use bootstrap-vue's grid system

```
<b-dropdown-item class="vertical-container" href="#">
   <router-link class="links" v-for="routes in links"
     v-bind:key="routes.id"
     :to="`${routes.page}`">{{routes.text}}</router-link>
</b-dropdown-item>
```

```css
.vertical-container {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 gap: 1rem;
}
.vertical-container > * {
 display: block;
}
```

Or you can use bootstrap's utility class **(Recommended)** `flex-column`

```
<b-dropdown-item class="d-flex flex-column" href="#">
   <router-link class="links d-block" v-for="routes in links"
     v-bind:key="routes.id"
     :to="`${routes.page}`">{{routes.text}}</router-link>
</b-dropdown-item>
```

Comment: Thank you @Swapnil Soni I have tried both solutions but the items in my drop-down are still aligned horizontally and not stacked vertically.

Comment: can you try setting as `d-block` class to `router-link`

Comment: Hi @Swapnil Soni. Would you know how to add a separation between the links in the drop-down? Currently, they all appear in the same box without being separated.

Comment: You can add margins. Read more about spacing from here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/